# How can I send login info in JSON format to a Web API using HTTP Cookies? - .NET Maui Application

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net, maui

> The API uses HTTP Cookies for authentication.
>
> The first call to any GET API endpoint (that does not require authentication) returns the cookies that are needed for authenticated API requests. The SID (session id) cookie and the csrftoken cookie. It is recommended to use the /api/_initial endpoint for this.
>
> The value in the csrftoken cookie needs to be passed in an X-Csrf-Token HTTP header for all except GET requests to mitigate Cross Site Request Forgeries.
>
> /api/_login [POST] Requests must have the following JSON body:

```
{
     "username": string,
     "password": string 
}
```

> If the username and password matches, the user object is returned. Otherwise, a 401 (unauthorized) error is
> returned.

Here is the code I have so far, which is returning a 401 Unauthorized despite using valid credentials.  I'm sure that there's some basic component I don't understand about what I'm trying to do, ignoring that I haven't implemented the LoginData class yet.  I'm just trying to get this to work in its most basic form at this point before breaking it out into an MVVM implementation in the app.  I'm hoping someone will be willing to take a look and see if they can spot where I'm going wrong and what I should look into next to make some progress on this:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Net.Http.Json;

namespace App.Views;

public class LoginData
{
    [JsonPropertyName("username")] public string Username { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("password")] public string Password { get; set; }
}

public partial class SubscriptionsPage : ContentPage
{
    public SubscriptionsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //set url for api endpoint to initialize session and retrieve SID and CSRF tokens
        var uri = new Uri("https://discuit.net/api/_initial");

        //create http client and request message to obtain SID and CSRF token from response headers
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);
        var httpResponseMessage = httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage).Result;

        //get response headers to retrieve Session ID and CSRF token
        var headersResult = httpResponseMessage.Headers;

        //get Session ID and CSRF token into variables
        var cookies = httpResponseMessage.Headers.GetValues("Set-Cookie");

        var cookieList = new List<string>();

        //store the needed cookies in a variable for use in POST url
        foreach (var cookie in cookies)
        {
            // Split the cookie string by ';'
            var parts = cookie.Split(';');

            // Get the first part, which contains the name and value
            var nameValue = parts[0];

            //add each part to the cookieList List
            cookieList.Add(nameValue);
        }
        
        //store each part into a variable to add to the cookies for the POST request
        var SID = cookieList[0];
        var csrftoken = cookieList[1];

        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("SID: " + SID);
        Console.WriteLine("csrftoken: " + csrftoken);
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");

        // set url to login endpoint
        var url = new Uri("https://discuit.net/api/_login");

        // create a cookie container and add the cookies to it so we can send a POST request to login
        var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = cookieContainer };
        var client = new HttpClient(handler);

        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("Adding Cookies to CookieContainer");
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");

        // add the cookies to the cookie container
        cookieContainer.Add(url, new Cookie("SID", SID));
        cookieContainer.Add(url, new Cookie("csrftoken", csrftoken));

        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("Creating JSON Data");
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");

        //create sample json with valid credentials
        //TODO: Get credentials from login page/use LoginData class
        var login = new LoginData { Username = "testaccount", Password = "testpassword" };

        // send json login request to server using new http client with handler with SID and csrftoken added as cookies
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("Posting Data...");
        Console.WriteLine("URL: " + url);
        Console.WriteLine("Data: " + login);
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");
        var result = client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, login).Result;

        if(result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("RESULT: " + result);
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");
            // TODO: Return token
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine($"The web API returned an error: {result.StatusCode}");
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("RESULT: " + result);
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output I'm getting in return:

```
> [DOTNET] -----------------------------------------
> [DOTNET] SID: SID=qP7salkaN7qyWpLWsZcaK7akvx728b9Vij00
> [DOTNET] csrftoken: csrftoken=Fa9MJF8iA3y6i-NaZOasSelQjd0Kue8Hg7H7aEy6-x0=
> [DOTNET] -----------------------------------------
> [DOTNET] -----------------------------------------
> [DOTNET] Adding Cookies to CookieContainer
> [DOTNET] -----------------------------------------
> [DOTNET] -----------------------------------------
> [DOTNET] Creating JSON Data
> [DOTNET] -----------------------------------------
> [DOTNET] -----------------------------------------
> [DOTNET] Posting Data...
> [DOTNET] URL: https://example.net/api/_login
> [DOTNET] Data: Disc.Views.LoginData
> [DOTNET] -----------------------------------------
> [DOTNET] -----------------------------------------
> [DOTNET] The web API returned an error: Unauthorized
> [DOTNET] -----------------------------------------
> [DOTNET] -----------------------------------------
> [DOTNET] RESULT: StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
> [DOTNET] {
> [DOTNET]   Cache-Control: no-store
> [DOTNET]   Date: Wed, 26 Jul 2023 18:32:39 GMT
> [DOTNET]   Set-Cookie: SID=15ka07TA3UqoNWjU46mmCiiOdOJFEPXLFxcy; Path=/; Expires=Sat, 20 Jul 2024 18:32:39 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=Lax
> [DOTNET]   X-Android-Received-Millis: 1690396360195
> [DOTNET]   X-Android-Response-Source: NETWORK 401
> [DOTNET]   X-Android-Selected-Protocol: http/1.1
> [DOTNET]   X-Android-Sent-Millis: 1690396360118
> [DOTNET]   Content-Length: 39
> [DOTNET]   Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
> [DOTNET] }
> [DOTNET] -----------------------------------------
```

Summary: Trying to pass the login data to the API and get a 200 success return code (and the user object).  Getting a 401 unauthorized.

---

**See selected answer**, it set me on the right path.  Here is the working code I ended up with, now will get this into MVVM and move on to the next step.

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace App.Views;

public class LoginData
{
    [JsonPropertyName("username")] public string Username { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("password")] public string Password { get; set; }
}

public partial class SubscriptionsPage : ContentPage
{
    public SubscriptionsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // set url for api endpoint to initialize session
        var uri = new Uri("https://discuit.net/api/_initial");

        // create http client and request message to obtain SID and CSRF token from response headers
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        handler.UseCookies = true;
        handler.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);

        HttpResponseMessage repsonse = client.GetAsync(uri).Result;
        CookieCollection cookies = handler.CookieContainer.GetCookies(uri);

        // create new Dictionary to store cookie data
        var cookieList = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        // get Session ID and CSRF token into variables
        foreach ( Cookie cookie in cookies)
        {
            cookieList.Add(cookie.Name, cookie.Value);
        }

        var SID = cookieList["SID"];
        var csrftoken = cookieList["csrftoken"];

        // new variable url set to login endpoint
        var url = new Uri("https://discuit.net/api/_login");

        // create a cookie container and add the SID to the api/_login url
        CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        cookieContainer.Add(url, new Cookie("SID", SID));

        // Add X-CSRF-Token to client
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-csrf-token", csrftoken);

        // create sample json with valid credentials
        // TODO: Get credentials from login page once this is working
        var login = new LoginData { Username = "testaccount", Password = "testpassword" };

        // send json login request to server using new http client with handler
        var result = client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, login).Result;
        
        if(result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("StatusCode: " + result.StatusCode);
            Console.WriteLine("RESULT: " + result);
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");
            // TODO: Return token
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine($"The web API returned an error: {result.StatusCode}");
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("RESULT: " + result);
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Use logging on your server, to see exactly what the server received. And why it rejected it. Use Postman to test server response independently of app.

Comment: Thanks @ToolmakerSteve!  Unfortunately, it isn't my server but an open web API I'm hitting: https://github.com/previnder/discuit-docs/blob/master/api.md#endpoints

Comment: are you sure the API works?  This appears to be a brand new project

Comment: Even though its not your server, the second part of my comment still applies: verify what works with server, without calling from app. Postman is commonly used for this.

Comment: Much appreciated @ToolmakerSteve - I'll add this to my toolbox, I'm sure I will need it!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comments and output, SID and csrftoken contain both key and value.

That doesn't seem right, when you create the Cookie `new Cookie(..)` you must specify key and value seperatly.

```
var cookieList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (var cookie in cookies)
{
   // Split the cookie string by ';'
   var parts = cookie.Split(';');

   // Split again to get key and value
   var parts2 = parts[0].Split('=');

   //add each part to the cookieList List
   cookieList.Add(parts2[0], parts2[1]);
}

var SID = cookieList["SID"];
var csrftoken = cookieList["csrftoken"];
```

Or better lookup HttpWebResponse.Cookies[key] to get the value.

Also, according to the short documentation you posted, the csrf token might need to be passed as a http header (X-Csrf-Token) not a cookie.

Comment: Thank you! This set me on the right path.  I'll add the code I ended up with that is giving me a successful login up top.